# Color icon in ng-grid based on booleans

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

So I have some JavaScript as follows:

```
$scope.gridTasks = {
        data: 'tasks'
        , multiSelect: false
        , sortInfo: { fields: ['DueSoon', 'SeenByOwner'], directions: ['asc'] }
        , columnDefs: [
           { field: 'ID', displayName: 'ID', visible: false }
           , { field: 'SeenByOwner', displayName: '', width: '17', cellTemplate: '<p><i tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip="You haven\'t looked at this yet." class="{{row.entity.DueSoon ? \'glyphicon glyphicon-fire\' : (!row.entity.SeenByOwner ? \'glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\' : \'\')}}" style="color: {{row.entity.DueSoon ? \'red\' : \'orange\'}};font-size:15px; padding-top:5px"></i></p>' }
           , { field: 'Priority.Name', displayName: 'Priority' }
           , { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description' }
           , { field: 'CreatedOn', displayName: 'Created', cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'', visible: $scope.completed }
           , { field: 'Completed', displayName: 'Closed', cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'', visible: !$scope.completed && $scope.completed != undefined }
           , {
               cellTemplate: '<div>' +
                      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="margin-top: 4px" ng-click="editTask(row.entity)">Open</button></div>'
               , width: '9%'
           }
        ]
    };
```

First, in the column for "SeenByOwner", I'm attempting to check if DueSoon is set to true.  If so, I want to display a glyphicon in red with the fire icon.  If not, I want to check if SeenByOwner is true.  If it is, I want to display a different glyphicon in orange.

As of right now, I can get the different glyphicons displaying properly, and neither will display if both Booleans are set to false.  Great so far!

The issue is they're displaying in black and I can't figure out how to get them to display in their appropriate colors without completely shoving duplicate style="" attributes into each part of the in-line if.

Another issue is that the ng-grid isn't sorting properly based on SortInfo.  It works fine to sort by SeenByOwner if the only field I have in fields is SeenByOwner but when I add DueSoon it gets wonky.

I'm trying to get this going in a Fiddle thing (sorry I'm new to web development) but I'm not sure how to get it to import all of the libraries we use in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `ng-style` if you want to stick with inline style rather than using css class

```
ng-style="{color: row.entity.DueSoon ? 'red' : 'orange'}
```

Comment: So looks like this might be working - what's the reasoning behind it requiring one set of braces {} versus the other typical dual braces {{}}?

Comment: @Friend  because `{{}}` is nothing but interpolation directive that will not work inside angular directive.. you can directly access scope variable inside angular directive by specifying there name directly..The reason `{}` is needed here is ng-style required json object. which will then applied as inline style

Comment: Completely understood.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

you could use ng-class.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myCssClass': SeenByOwner }"></div>
```

Basically, the above would attach .myCssClass to your div, if your property SeenByOwner is true.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using a .css file? Like an in-line way of duplicating this behavior?

Comment: In your html tag, use:
<div style="color: {{ SeenByOwner ? 'red' : 'blue' }}"></div>